# In ng-repeat 3*3 matrix is not creating

Tags: angularjs

Response I am getting from server

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "members":[
                   [\"5\",\"11\",\"24\",null,null,null,null,\"71\",\"88\"],
                   [null,null,\"25\",null,\"42\",\"53\",\"61\",null,\"90\"],
                   [\"7\",\"14\",null,\"32\",\"50\",null,\"65\",null,null]
                  ]
    },{
        "id":2,
        "members":[
                   [\"1\",null,null,null,\"44\",null,\"61\",\"71\",\"82\"],
                   [\"4\",\"19\",\"22\",null,null,null,\"68\",\"76\",null],
                   [null,null,\"30\",\"34\",\"50\",\"58\",null,null,\"83\"]
                  ]
    },{
        "id":3,
        "members":[
                   [\"6\",\"11\",null,\"31\",null,null,\"61\",\"76\",null],
                   [null,null,\"22\",\"37\",\"42\",null,\"64\",null,\"86\"],
                   [null,\"17\",null,null,\"47\",\"56\",null,\"77\",\"87\"]
                  ]
    }   
];
```

By repeating the data in html it showing like this

5 1 1 2 4 7 1 8 8   2 5 4 2 5 3 6 1 9 0 7 1 4 3 2 5 0 6 5

1 4 4 6 1 7 1 8 2   4 1 9 2 2 6 8 7 6   3 0 3 4 5 0 5 8 8 3

6 1 1 3 1 6 1 7 6   2 2 3 7 4 2 6 4 8 6 1 7 4 7 5 6 7 7 8 7

I want to repeat the data like this 3*3 matrix

```
5 11 24 "" "" "" "" 71 88
"" "" 25 "" 42 53 61 "" 90  
7 14 "" 32 50 "" 65 "" ""
```

This is one matrix like this I want to repeat

```js
for(var i=0;i<$scope.ticketsData.length;i++){
 $scope.ticket.push(JSON.parse($scope.ticketsData[i].ticket));
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in ticket track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">
        <span ng-repeat="v in col track by $index">
         <span>{{v[0]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[1]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[2]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[3]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[4]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[5]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[6]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[7]}}</span>
         <span>{{v[8]}}</span>
        </span>
        
         </td>
                
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my code 
I tried but I am not getting the correct response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like to this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
    "id": 1,
    "members": [
      ["5", "11", "24", null, null, null, null, "71", "88"],
      [null, null, "25", null, "42", "53", "61", null, "90"],
      ["7", "14", null, "32", "50", null, "65", null, null]
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "members": [
      ["1", null, null, null, "44", null, "61", "71", "82"],
      ["4", "19", "22", null, null, null, "68", "76", null],
      [null, null, "30", "34", "50", "58", null, null, "83"]
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "members": [
      ["6", "11", null, "31", null, null, "61", "76", null],
      [null, null, "22", "37", "42", null, "64", null, "86"],
      [null, "17", null, null, "47", "56", null, "77", "87"]
    ]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="row in groups track by $index">
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="col in row.members track by $index">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="v in col track by $index">{{v== null ? '""':v}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working but one issue is that how will I seperate one member array from another array

Comment: why didn't you have any action to my answer?Did this answer solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry I was on bedrest, so I didn't do any action @ Hadi

Comment: excuse me really :(